# Adding local storage or cookies to JQuery shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm building shopping-cart-like feature with JQuery. So far I can add and remove items from the cart without a problem.

However, I would like the items in the list to persist if the user refreshes the page or decides to navigate away.

Here is a snippet of the functioning cart without any local storage.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-primary").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
    toggleText($(this));

    if (!$(`li[data-attribute="${e.target.id}"]`).length) {
      addItem(e.target.id);
    } else {
      $(`li[data-attribute="${e.target.id}"]`).remove();
    }
    setBadge();
    $(".btn-danger").click(function() {
      removeItem($(this).parent("li"));
    });
  });
});

function removeItem(item) {
  $(`#${item.data("attribute")}`).removeClass("btn-warning");
  toggleText($(`#${item.data("attribute")}`));
  item.remove();
  setBadge();
}

function addItem(item) {
  $("ul").append(
    `<li class='well' data-attribute='${item}'>
       ${$(`.${item}-container p`).text()} 
       <button class='btn btn-danger'>-</button>
     </li>`
   );
}

function setBadge() {
  $(".badge").remove();
  $("h3").after("<span class='badge'>" + $("li").length + "</span>");
}

function toggleText(item) {
  if (item.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
    item.text("-");
  } else {
    item.text("+");
  }
}
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline;
}

.list-inline {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

li.well {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-1-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 1
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-1">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-2-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 2
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-2">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-3-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 3
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-3">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-4-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 4
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-4">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <h3>The List </h3>
  <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline"></ul>
</div>
```

Here is a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/RZKOqg)** of my attempt to incorporate local storage into the cart such that the items are stored. As you can see in the demo, it's not working.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/VzpQzM?editors=1010

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  
  if(localStorage.getItem("cart") != null){
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).items;
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
      addItem(items[i]);
      $('#' + items[i]).toggleClass("btn-warning");
      toggleText(items[i]);
    }
    setBadge();
  }
  
  $(".btn-primary").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
    toggleText($(this).attr('id'));

    if (!$(`li[data-attribute="${e.target.id}"]`).length) {
      addItem(e.target.id);
    } else {
      $(`li[data-attribute="${e.target.id}"]`).remove();
    }
    setBadge();
    setLocalStorage(e.target.id, 0);
    $(".btn-danger").on('click', function() {
      removeItem($(this).parent("li"));
      setLocalStorage($(this).data('id'), 1);
    });
  });
  
  $(".btn-danger").on('click', function() {
    removeItem($(this).parent("li"));
    setLocalStorage($(this).data('id'), 1);
  });
});

function removeItem(item) {
  console.log(item);
  var id = item[0].attributes[1].value;
  $(`#${id}`).removeClass("btn-warning");
  toggleText(id);
  item.remove();
  setBadge();
}

function addItem(item) {
  $("ul").append(
        `<li class='well' data-attribute='${item}'>
${$(`.${item}-container p`).text()} 
<button class='btn btn-danger' data-id='${item}'>-</button>
</li>`
      );  
}

function setBadge() {
  $(".badge").remove();
  $("h3").after("<span class='badge'>" + $("li").length + "</span>");
}

function toggleText(item) {
  if ($('#' + item).hasClass("btn-warning")) {
    $('#' + item).text("-");
  } else {
    $('#' + item).text("+");
  }
}


var cart = {};
cart.items = [];

function setLocalStorage(id, flag) {
  if(flag) {
    cart.items.splice(cart.items.indexOf(id), 1);
  } else {
    cart.items.push(id);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(cart));
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
}
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline;
}

.list-inline {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

li.well {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-1-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 1
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-1" data-id="item-1">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-2-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 2
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-2" data-id="item-2">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-3-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 3
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-3" data-id="item-3">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="well item-4-container">
        <p class="lead">
          Item 4
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="item-4" data-id="item-4">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <h3>The List</h3>
  <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline"></ul>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This helps a lot. When no items are added to the cart and I add some, they items persist after refreshing the page. 

However, when I refresh and update the persisted store, the updates don't persist upon subsequent refresh. Are you seeing this on your end?

e.g. 

- I add items 1 and 2, then refresh. The items are there. All is well. 

- Then I remove item 1, and all the items are wiped clean on refresh. 

I also am experiencing inconsistencies when adding items to the persisted store after refresh. Do you see this?

Comment: I have updated the codePen https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/VzpQzM . Have a look...

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you some steps for this.
Firstly make an array of items for putting all added items in it.
Write getLocalStorage/ setLocalstorage methods.
On page load , check for the array of items, if it's empty, do nothing and if it has some length, create dynamic template and append in the ul.

While you add items in your function, keep adding the same in the array by push function and simultaneously set it to localstorage. Splice the array in case of remove item at proper index.

You will get the solution. Please give it a try with above steps.